# LXD container: What does apparmor mount error -13 mean?

Tags: lxd

I have PiHole inside LXD container (on Ubuntu Server). It works very well, but I can see plenty of such errors in server's dmesg:

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1613833741.169:605): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match" error=-13 profile="lxd-pihole2_</var/snap/lxd/common/lxd>" name="/run/systemd/unit-root/bin/" pid=3219245 comm="(ionclean)" flags="ro, remount, noatime, bind"
```

What can I do with it?